# How to cluster Elevation map data

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, point-cloud-library

I have used stereo vision system in C++ for obstacle detection and produced point clouds of the scene. Then I calculated digital elevation map (DEM) of the scene.

Now I want to cluster the objects that are found in the environment. I'm new at c++ .

Comment: Well do it then. You have our blessings! oh wait, You aren't here for the blessing? Well then try something mate and come back with a specific problem when you hit a roadblock. No one is going to code the entire thing for you.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I know, but i want to guide me what algorithm should be i use.

Answer (score 0):

You should use segmentation for detect the objects. then for the recognition you may use deep learning

Comment: for obstacle detection which one is better  occupancy map or elevation map?